# Scope resolution in Javascript using 'with' keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, javascript-engine

There seems to be a strange behavior in Javascript with hoisting and scoping , when using 'with' keyword.

I understand the usage of 'with' is considered taboo, but came across this in one of the frameworks and had to deal with it. But nonetheless,

Could anyone explain why if we have a 'with' block , the variables that are declared but undefined are resolved using the with object but this is not the case with the closure variables.

To demo, see the output of the following code:  http://jsfiddle.net/ftK2Z/1/

```
var x = 90;

function test1(){
    var address = {
         street: 'Haight',
         aptNum: 2
     };


    with (address){
      alert(aptNum + ":" +  x); // this  outputs 2 : undefined. 
      var aptNum = 100,
      x = 10 ;
    }
}
```

Checked with google chrome.

Note: that I understand JS hoisting and see why having var statements after the alert is an issue but the main thing I am trying to figure out it is , 
during scope resolution at the alert statement,  both 'aptNum' and 'x' should be undefined in local scope due to hoisting, so they should be taken as 'declared but not defined'.

But still, aptNum is output as '2'.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have block scope. Your `var aptNum` in the `with` is a variable local to the enclosing function. The properties of the object provided to `with` becomes accessible as variables within the block, which is why you get `2`. You can't add new properties to the object using `var`, though you can update existing properties without referencing the object directly.

Comment: @squint thanks. this seems to be somehow creating a block scope with 'with' object properties populated in the local scope. and then scope goes away after the block. but since there is no block scope in JS, this is a strange behavior

Comment: Yes, it's behavior is strange and confusing, which is why people recommend to avoid it. It can be useful though. It is a scope of sorts, but it's not a typical variable scope. The `var` isn't constrained to the block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `with` block, the variable `aptNum` is shadowed by `address.aptNum`, and `x` refers to the local variable (never `address.x`, as there isn't such a property).

Considering that, and hoisting, your code is equivalent to:

```
var x = 90;
function test1(){

    var aptNum; // hoisted
    var x;      // hoisted

    var address = {
        street: 'Haight',
        aptNum: 2
    };

    with (address){

        // any reference to aptNum or street inside the with block
        // is actually referencing address.aptNum and address.street

        alert(aptNum + ":" +  x); // this  outputs 2 : undefined. 
                                  // as expected, because there is no address.x
                                  // and the local x is undefined at this point

        aptNum = 100; // this assigns to address.aptNum
                      // the variable aptNum is shadowed by address.aptNum

        x = 10; // this assigns to the local x inside the function 
                // (again because there is no address.x)
    }
}
```

Comment: so, basically, for aptNum inside the with block, it updates the address.aptNum but for x it updates the local 'x'. if we check the values outside the block for x and aptNum, this proves it. http://jsfiddle.net/ftK2Z/4/.  Thanks. this makes sense.

Comment: Exactly. It also proves how with statements can be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

From fiddle:

```
with(address){
    $('#output').text('aptNum : ' + aptNum + ",   x : " + x ); 
    var aptNum = 100,
        x = 10 ;
}
```

The variable `x` is being redeclared in the body of the `with` statement (see preceding `var` keyword). Variable declarations are hoisted, so `x` is being defined temporarily to `undefined`, then finally redefined to `10` after the value has already been logged.

In this updated fiddle, I changed the variable declaration statement to a simple assignment statement, which produces the expected behavior of logging the value of `x` to be `90`. See http://jsfiddle.net/ftK2Z/3/

Comment: I am not concerned with how i can have x equal to x. Actually , i am trying to demonstrate the scope resolution peculiarity here. The question is why the difference in resolution for x vs aptNum

Comment: That's been explained already by showing the misuse of `var` keyword on `x`.

Answer (score 1):

> Using with is not recommended, and is forbidden in ECMAScript 5 strict mode. The recommended alternative is to assign the object whose properties you want to access to a temporary variable.

It does not like having a global variable. I think its due to the fact x is outside the scope of the address object. You can pass the parameters into the function and it works.

```
var x = 90;
test(x);
```

Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cEURa/)

More info on with [JavaScript with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you called `x` (which WILL be expected as a property of `address`) before even declaring `x`. `x` in the `with` scope doesn't refer to the `x` declared outside the function. The engine is trying to read the value of `address.x` which doesn't exist, of course. That's the reason. Concerning `with`, since `aptNum` is 're'-declared as a variable in that scope, it DOESN'T refer to `address`'s `aptNum`.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
alert(aptNum + ":" +  x);
var aptNum = 100,
      x = 10 ;
```

is `var`-ing `aptNum` and `x` within the `with`. `var` is hoisted so it can also be considered as

```
var aptNum, x;
alert(aptNum + ":" +  x);
aptNum = 100, x = 10;
```

It is now easy to see why they are `undefined`. You probably didn't want to use the `var` here.

Comment: I see your point. But the thing that makes it interesting is: aptNum is not output as 'undefined'. It is resolving the value from the address.aptNum which is '2'